# How to interfere other windows program (with C#, C++ or Java)

Tags: c#, java, c++

Sorry for the unclear title,but my english is not good enough to describes my question in one line.

**For example**, i have a udp gaming program called **Garena**,its halt user for 5s after every 
attemp to join room (by some client-code i guess),therefor i downloaded another program which called **Garena Auto-joiner**(C++) ,this program bypass 5sec waiting and attemp to join room every second,ultil succeed.
**For example** Warcraft III do not have manabar show on top of heroes(nomally just have Hpbar),but when i download **Manabar** and run it after in game, it even render a manabar below Hpbar

What i want to ask is: "how can it do that?","is it related with cracking in anyway?","Can a Java program achieve similar use?".
Thank for your supports!

Comment: I think you can remove java from this discussion.

Comment: A Java program would be able to do that but it may need some native code help ...

Comment: Title say C#, tag say C++, which is it?

Comment: @Erik i have updated the title and tags of the question

Comment: err,i just want to know the way they do it, as they dont teach this kind of programing in my school

Comment: @Singgum3b Have you post your question gamedev.stackexchange.com ? I think you'll find gurus there ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a *lot* of ways to interfer with other programs. For some samples:

- [DLL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) - using one of several methods
- [Packet Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_injection) - for networked programs
- Windows [Debug API](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx&ei=Yh2LTeC7CYqVOvu9iIMO&usg=AFQjCNHslwgLUDjCRYUTv_0DSMgHWwbfBQ)
- [Code Injection](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx&ei=yR2LTdj4E4aVOt35qIwO&usg=AFQjCNGq7cdEECXc9ZcP8mDlrOnI2W3m_Q) - modifying the running program

Comment: Wow, thank a lot! I wonder if they teach those thing in university -_-

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with C/C++ as their access to memory and other running processes is more straight forward. This is a good resource for understanding game hacking: [cheat engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/)

The site's forum can provide more hands-on coding help.